# Setting the LD_PRELOAD environment variable for commands run without typing the full path

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, ld-preload

I'm playing around with LD_PRELOAD and have produced a library that simply wraps puts() in a function that converts the string to be printed to uppercase before printing. I then export the LD_PRELOAD variable as so

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD=/home/adrian/test/myputs.so
```

Now the behaviour works as expected when running the command

```
$ /bin/pwd
/HOME/ADRIAN/TEST
```

But it does not work when runing like this

```
$ pwd
/home/adrian/test
```

What is the mechanism that's causing the LD_PRELOAD environment variable to be ignored in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because`pwd` is `shell builtin command` - see `man bash` or [docs here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins). So if you write

```
$ pwd
```

Then the builtin command is launched. If you tell it the path, it will execute the ELF binary and use the LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: Thanks! After a quick search I found I can disable the builtin pwd using `enable -n pwd` and now it behaves as expected.

Comment: @eltommo, wow, I was not aware of this possiblity. Interesting!